# php mysql session redirecting to main page with wrong username and password

Tags: php, mysql, session

My login using session in php mysql is working with or without the correct username and password...here are the codes...

here is my login.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$records = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('login', $records);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT id, username, password
        FROM login
        WHERE username = '$username';";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header("Location: http://localhost/GuidanceRecord/login.html");
}

$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
//$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );

if($password != $userData['password']) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header("Location: http://localhost/GuidanceRecord/login.html");
}else{ // Redirect to home page after successful login.
    //session_regenerate_id();
    //$_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $userData['id'];
    //$_SESSION['sess_username'] = $userData['username'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    //session_write_close();
    header("Location: http://localhost/GuidanceRecord/ViewRecords.php");
}
?>
```

here is my login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/global.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/signin.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     <span class="span12">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
         <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please log in</h2>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" style="width:100%;">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" style="width:100%;">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Log in" name="login">
        </form>
     </span>

 </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my session in everypage of my project...

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/GuidanceRecord/login.html");
}
?>
```

I have a database for login called login...
i have 3 columns in my table named: ID(which is autoincrement and primary key), username, and password...

thanks for the help anyway...

Comment: What problem you facing ? Is it redirecting even if you insert correct username & password ?

Comment: @Rikesh actually it's logging in even you typed wrong username and password...

Comment: Problem with invalid username also user logged in to the application.

Comment: Have you debug ? What you're getting in `$userData['password']` & `$password` ?

Comment: No, not yet...im figuring out what's wrong...I think i'm having problem in getting $userData['password'] & $password...because my login.php and login.html are of different page...

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: @Quentin yeah, i add name="username"
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" style="width:100%;">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" style="width:100%;">
and it hits me an another problem...I cant pass my login form now...
I know that it should work now, but it's not...

Comment: @user3429260 — The name attribute has nothing to do with my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download working code from here!! [Download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7k5ortjgpt2kan/test.zip)

and the database is as previous :) . I hope it will help you :)

Comment: On each page just you need to check following code to verify user is log in or not!! '<?php
// there is no need to start ssssion again!!! as you do privius
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){
header("location:./index.php");

}
?>'

Comment: It work in my system! can you tale me what is error??

Comment: wait i also have ID in the database...
so I have 3 columns....ID, username and password...

I can't tell what's the problem in my system...im sorry...

Comment: hay, i understand the problem! wait i will send you a code okay :)

Comment: i'll wait for it... :)

Comment: hay now you can download my code from [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7k5ortjgpt2kan/test.zip) . database same as previous

Comment: It was my pleasure. :) Chill !!

Answer (score 0):

You must have to write username and password name which you are missing in login form. Check it. You only added place holder not input name.

Comment: you mean i have to do it like this...and insert in top of my login.html?

<?php 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
?>

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" style="width:100%;">

Comment: Im, getting another problem...now that I put the name="username" and name="password"...
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" style="width:100%;">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" style="width:100%;">

now i can't log in...im always redirecting in the login.html...

Comment: You have to debug your login.php file what you get as user name and password?

Comment: what should be my query to display the username and password? I'm sorry I'm new to php...